# Can we use a command to append any text to the current edited file or after prompt

Tags: matlab

1) suppose I use the 'edit' command only an unnamed file 'untitled'.
   can I use any command to append any text to the file 'untitled'?

2) Is there a command that can write a command after the prompt symbol >> w/o pressing enter. Like

```
>> doit
```

This is different from printf. printf('doit') does the following

```
doit
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add text in a file 'untitled.m' using a function doit()

```
function doit()
  fid = fopen('untitled.m','w'); % open file with write access
  fprintf(fid,'%s','This text will appear in untitled.m'); % write some text as string (%s)
  fclose(fid); % close the file (important!)
```